# Comment dit-on "I want to be able to give it away" en français?

Tags: expressions

Comment rend-on la phrase anglaise

> I want to be able to give it away.

en français ? La phrase suivante est-elle correcte ?

> Je veux pouvoir le donner.

Comment: Welcome to FSE. Your question needs editing. As it stands, it is not very clear what is your problem and it risks to be closed.

Comment: Give away may have several translations: https://www.deepl.com/fr/translator#en/fr/give%20away. Can you be more specific giving some context?

Comment: I did some editing myself. I hope it is ok for you.

Comment: Hello J.J and welcome to FSE. Can you please provide us with some more context for this question? The English expression "to give something away" can have different meanings and it would be nice to understand what you are trying to say here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Je voudrais en faire un don

ou

Je voudrais le donner [à quelqu’un]

Le “to be able to” appelle vraisemblablement le conditionnel, dans une forme plus recherchée que “pouvoir le donner” qui ne se rencontre pas en français, et sent très fort la traduction mot à mot :)

Comment: Merci.  As for further clarification.  If I am the head of a pharma company and my company discovers the vaccine for Covid.  I want to be able to give it away without charging the poor.  Of course, I may not be able to do so if my shareholders are hearltess and greedy.

Comment: So, the real translation would probably be more shomething like « Je voudrais en faire don [à l’humanité] », ou « Je voudrais pouvoir l’offrir », which implies a totally free to use meaning.

Comment: Merci encoure Gaétan

Comment: @J.J. If this answer is ok with you, you should select it.